# my qvector size is 5 but I get 10 output

Tags: qt

in first for loop when I wrote z.size() I get

> Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

and also in second for when I wrote z.size I get 10 output but size of z is 5 as you can see.
What is wrong .First 5 output is 0 and then rest is normal like 0 1 2 3 4 but I should have 5 output am I wrong

```
QVector<int> z(5);
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    z.push_back(i);
QString str;
for (int i = 0; i < z.size(); ++i)
{
    if (i > 0)
        str += " ";
    str += QString::number(z[i]);
}
ui->mbox->setText(str);

}
```

Comment: Please format the source code properly. I've done it this time for your, but you should be more careful next time. Also, there's a dangling `}` at the end of the code.

Comment: I didint copy whole part of my code."Also, there's a dangling">> That blongs to cilck action .thank you I will be more careful next time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the QVector z, you give the initial size of 5. That means that the vector contains 5 zeroes. Then you add five more ints, from 0 to 4. The fix is to change

```
QVector<int> z(5);
```

to

```
QVector<int> z;
```

Most often, QVector is not the best container to use, usually QList is much better. From Qt's documentation:

> For most purposes, QList is the right class to use. Its index-based
>   API is more convenient than QLinkedList's iterator-based API, and it
>   is usually faster than QVector because of the way it stores its items
>   in memory. It also expands to less code in your executable.

Comment: ok I will use qt list but professor wants us to use vector. Can we limit qvector size

Comment: By all means, you _can_ use QVector. But it doesn't make much sense to restrict the used container class to QVector, even in a homework. I think you should find out if your professor really meant QVector, or if he/she meant plain old C-style arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
z.push_back(i);
```

You just added 5 elements into the array.